# OverrideGraphicSettings in active view with RevitPythonShell

Tags: python, revit, revitpythonshell

I am trying to override graphics of a wall in a 3D view in Revit using RevitPythonshell. I managed to make this work in Dynamo with a Python Node.

So far I have the following code;

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
import Autodesk
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager 

from System.Collections.Generic import List


doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(doc)

walls = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls)
elements = walls.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).WhereElementIsNotElementType()


color = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Color(255,50,50)
ogs = OverrideGraphicSettings().SetProjectionFillColor(color)


for i in elements:
    doc.ActiveView.SetElementOverrides((i.Id), ogs)


TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()
```

When I run this in RevitPythonShell it does nothing. I get no error or anything. When I print `doc.ActiveView.SetElementOverrides((i.Id), ogs)` it returns None.

What am I missing here? I am in a 3D View in Revit which is the active view. I am starting and ending a transaction.

[Here](https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/projection-line-color-in-python/17012/3) is somewhat the same code in a Python node in Dynamo node.

Comment: `doc.ActiveView.SetElementOverrides((i.Id), ogs)` returning `None` is to be expected - what kind of result should it be otherwise?

Comment: as a first debugging step, I'd print out the `elements` variable. Maybe you're not collecting the elements you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few tweaks your code works:

```
import clr

clr.AddReference('RevitAPI') 
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI') 
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import * 
from Autodesk.Revit.UI import *

app = __revit__.Application
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document

elements = list(FilteredElementCollector(doc, doc.ActiveView.Id))

color = Color(255,50,50)
ogs = OverrideGraphicSettings().SetProjectionFillColor(color)

t = Transaction(doc, 'Color Walls')
t.Start()
try:
    for i in elements:
        if i.Category.Name == 'Walls':
            doc.ActiveView.SetElementOverrides((i.Id), ogs)
            print 'element overridden'
except Exception as e:
    print '- Failed to override -'
    print '- ' + str(e) + ' -'
t.Commit()
```

- When you pass a `View.Id` to the `FilteredElementCollector`, you collect
  everything visible in that view
- Transactions work a little differently in RevitPythonShell from Dynamo, you open an close them around the code thats actually modifying the database
- When youre inside a transaction, it pays to wrap code in a try/except block, as you need the transaction finish even if there are errors

Answer (score 1):

I managed to colorize the different type of walls in the following manner.

```
import clr 
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI') 
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI') 
import Autodesk
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import * 
from Autodesk.Revit.UI import *

from random import randint

app = __revit__.Application
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document

#elements = list(FilteredElementCollector(doc, doc.ActiveView.Id))
wall_collector = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls)
wall_instances = wall_collector.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).WhereElementIsNotElementType()



fill_patterns = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(FillPatternElement).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()

for i in fill_patterns:
    if i.Name == 'Solid fill':
        solid_fill = i.Id

element_list = []
element_name_list = []

for i in wall_instances:
    element_name_list.append(i.Name)
    element_list.append(i.Id)

wall_color_dict = {}
for i in set(element_name_list):
    wall_color_dict[i] = Color(randint(0,250), randint(0,250), randint(0,250))

t = Transaction(doc, 'Color Walls')

t.Start()

for i in wall_instances:
    for k, v in wall_color_dict.iteritems():
        if k == i.Name: 
            a=OverrideGraphicSettings().SetProjectionFillPatternId(solid_fill)
            b=OverrideGraphicSettings(a).SetProjectionFillColor(v)
            p = doc.ActiveView.SetElementOverrides(i.Id, a)
            c = doc.ActiveView.SetElementOverrides(i.Id, b)




t.Commit()
```

Before running the script:
[image: before]

After running the script:

[image]